# Symfony2 application structure best practices

Tags: php, symfony

For the past two months, I've been developing a Symfony2 web application. Now I've been going back through and trying to fix some issues with it, because it's gotten a little out of control and I want to make it easy to maintain.

My application is structured into a series of bundles like this:

```
src/AppName/HelpBundle
src/Appname/InterfaceBundle
src/AppName/ProductBundle
src/AppName/UserBundle
```

InterfaceBundle just contains several twig templates for the main layout, and each of the other bundles just extend that, e.g.:

```
{% extends 'AppNameInterfaceBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

---

For controllers, each controller directory has two sub directories: User and Admin, for example:

```
src/AppName/ProductBundle/Controller/Admin/ProductCategoryController.php
src/AppName/ProductBundle/Controller/User/ProductCategoryController.php
```

Is this the appropriate way to structure a Symfony application, or should it be done differently?

Comment: Seems completely structured and reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not very detailed but for what I see I think that what you could do is organize things in a way that AdminBundle and a UserBundle contain a set of generic services that allow you to build controllers reusing them.

Then you could have a series of bundles like ProductBundle that reuse/interact with these services. Use dependency injection in your controllers rather than extending the Symfony's Controller class; this way you can leverage service inheritance and build abstract controllers in your AdminBundle and UserBundle and use them to derive your specific controllers.

More in general I like to structure Symfony applications in a way that for each concern that is cross-cutting the application's domain (e.g. indexing of entities in a search engine, logging, generation of URLs and so on) I like to create a bundle that provides some abstractions to handle it; for each area of the domain (e.g. product management, user management etc.) then I like having a bundle that implements interfaces provided in the abstraction ones and that registers specific services to be used in the provided abstractions. Interfacing can be done in this case through the container's configuration and tagging systems.

The question was pretty generic and so my answer is too, if you want more details feel free to provide more details to your question.